# How to catch video files so as to play them offline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I am building a video app using angularjs/firebase. I want the app to work both offline/online.

Every other thing now works as I want. Except my video files can't play offline which I understand.

I was wondering if there is any angular directive or service to enable me cache files that are stored in firebase storage.

Or is there any idea as to how I can achieve this in angularjs.

I have references to my firebase storage files in my firebase database.

So basically I have the url for a file as so :

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gotube-xxxx.appspot.com/o/user…659ba91fb08b78e2f6921?alt=media&token=c050d890-61c7-4c2f-a044-64906c06025c
```

Is it possible to cache this file to a browser so it can play offline?